# How to make a TeamsChannelAccount to ConversationReference for one-on-one Microsoft Bot Conversations?

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to start a new one-on-one conversation with a user in a MS Teams channel. I am able to retrieve their TeamsChannelAccount information. I have tried creating a new conversationReference like below:

```
Activity newActivity = new Activity()
{
  Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
  Conversation = new ConversationAccount
   {
     AadObjectId = member.AadObjectId,
     Id = member.Id
   },
};
ConversationReference newReference = new ConversationReference()
{
  Conversation = newActivity.Conversation,
  ServiceUrl = turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl
};
newReference.Conversation = newActivity.Conversation;
_conversationReferences.AddOrUpdate(member.Id, newReference,(key,value) => newReference);
```

Once creating the new conversationReference, I was trying to add it to the global conversationReferences dictionary to be read in the following block of code:

```
foreach (var conversationReference in _conversationReferences.Values)
  {
     await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, BotCallback, 
     default(CancellationToken));
  }
```

What would be the correct way of creating a conversationReference using TeamsChannelAccount object?
Is this even possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at sample [57.teams-conversation-bot](https://github.com/stevkan/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot), in particular, the [line 94](https://github.com/stevkan/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot/Bots/TeamsConversationBot.cs#L94) code block.

This particular samples goes over how to message all users, so you would need to adjust your code to point to a solitary user, as you demonstrate in your posted code. But, it should give you a good understanding of how to go about creating a conversation reference and sending a message.

For quick reference, here is the above linked code.

```cs
private async Task MessageAllMembersAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  var teamsChannelId = turnContext.Activity.TeamsGetChannelId();
  var serviceUrl = turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl;
  var credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(_appId, _appPassword);
  ConversationReference conversationReference = null;

  var members = await TeamsInfo.GetMembersAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

  foreach (var teamMember in members)
  {
    var proactiveMessage = MessageFactory.Text($"Hello {teamMember.GivenName} {teamMember.Surname}. I'm a Teams conversation bot.");

    var conversationParameters = new ConversationParameters
    {
      IsGroup = false,
      Bot = turnContext.Activity.Recipient,
      Members = new ChannelAccount[] { teamMember },
      TenantId = turnContext.Activity.Conversation.TenantId,
    };

    await ((BotFrameworkAdapter)turnContext.Adapter).CreateConversationAsync(
      teamsChannelId,
      serviceUrl,
      credentials,
      conversationParameters,
      async (t1, c1) =>
      {
        conversationReference = t1.Activity.GetConversationReference();
        await ((BotFrameworkAdapter)turnContext.Adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(
          _appId,
          conversationReference,
          async (t2, c2) =>
          {
            await t2.SendActivityAsync(proactiveMessage, c2);
          },
          cancellationToken);
      },
      cancellationToken);
  }

  await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("All messages have been sent."), cancellationToken);
}
```

Hope of help!

Comment: Turns out this, in order to this without being in the context of the team it helps saving parameters such as teamsChannelId, serviceUrl, and of course your tenantID. This was the exact code needed to send proactive messages within context, but when outside ensure that you have those three necessary items.